# Plasma 5 on Fedora giving "Could not start d-bus. Can you call qdbus?"

Tags: fedora, kde, fedora-20, kde-plasma-workspace

I cannot start Plasma 5 in Fedora 20. I have installed using the following method:

```
yum install kf5-\*
dnf copr enable dvratil/plasma-5
yum install plasma-5
```

Everything went fine and `plasmashell` will run. However, when I try to log into a Plasma shell from the display manager, I get `Could not start d-bus. Can you call qdbus?`. I can run qdbus just fine.

I have seen a few bug reports in other distros that look similar, but don't seem applicable. What causes this?

Additional information: I have discovered that the source of the error above was that the startkde.sh script in /usr/bin/ was not finding the path for qdbus. It uses the tool qtpaths to locate this path. For some reason qtpath, which is provided by qt5-qttools, was not present. Once I installed qt5-qttools, the previous error is passed. However, something is still awry. I can open programs, but there is no menu or background. I'm am now under the assumption that there is some unlisted dependency, of which both qt5-qttools and whatever allows the rest of Plasma to be loaded are parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by running `yum install qt5-qttools`. If it does not work for you, please run /usr/bin/startkde in a tty and post the error output.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know why it was not working before. As you can see in my edit, I had installed `qt5-qttools`. The panel was missing. I think it may have been something really silly, like the panel had loaded on my unopened laptop screen. Nevertheless, it is working now. `qt5-qttools` should probably be marked as a dependency.

Comment: I also got problems because yum always wanted to install the KDE 4 German language pack by default which is not compatible, however I think Plasma5 is really nice :) I also expect better Fedora support soon because of its policy to quickly integrade newest developments.